# TYPO3 own extension Detailpage with form and counter

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.7.x

I have a TYPO3 car extension wir the model "car" there is a field of *maximale number of cars*. 
On my ShowAction I need a form. When the form is submitted, the number of *maximale number of cars* should be reduced -1. "

How do I do that? With PowerMail or form? How can I make the reduction -1?

I'm looking forward to any help :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the object to the showAction. In the Show.html, you will have a form with a submit which should process updateAction. In updateAction, you will increment the maximale number of cars by 1 and update the repository.

For example:

showAction

```
   /**
   *
   * @param \Vendor\Extname\Domain\Model\Car $car
   * @ignorevalidation $car
   * @return void
   */
   public function showAction(\Vendor\Extname\Domain\Model\Car $car = NULL)
   {
     $this->view->assign('car', $car);
   }
```

Show.html

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">

  <f:flashMessages />

    <f:form name="car" object="{car}" action="update">

    <!-- add any other properties you may wish to update here -->

    <f:form.submit value="Update" />

  </f:form>

</f:section>
```

updateAction

```
    /**
    *
    * @param \Vendor\Extname\Domain\Model\Car $car
    *
    */
    public function updateAction(\Vendor\Extname\Domain\Model\Car $car) 
    {
      $car->setMaximaleNumberOfCars($car->getMaximaleNumberOfCars()+1);
      $this->carRepository->update($car);
      $this->redirect('list');
    }
```

This was more or less written on the spot and is un-tested but it should give you the right idea.

Comment: Do you know an example of how to send the form by mail?

Answer (score 0):

After you submit the form, there should be a saveAction in the Controller. In this saveAction, you can access all field values. Before persisting them, you can change the field value.